# XCUITest - How to simulate locking of the device

Tags: ios, swift, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing XCUITests for my app in Swift, and I was wondering if it's possible to simulate the locking and unlocking of a device. I've looked at `XCUIApplication` methods but there don't seem to be any that allow me to lock the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.

Comment: And is unlikely to ever be possible as it is a security risk. It would allow the average person to build a brute force PIN cracker with ease.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107876/4504604) answer, there's a private method on XCUIDevice that you can call to lock the screen as follows:

```swift
XCUIDevice.shared.perform(NSSelectorFromString("pressLockButton"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but may be it is possible to do via some magic sentence like:

```
let siri = XCUIDevice().XCUISiriService // available since SDK 10.3
siri.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "siri, please lock my device")
```