# iOS, locking the device from code

Tags: ios, xctest

for testing purposes (making a screenshot of a local notification) i need to be able to lock the device (simulator) from code (either tests code or app code).
I've looked at a couple of answers from here (GSEventLockDevice), but they are quite old and didn't work for me

Comment: You may create an Apple script that will do that and use it in your code. (not from iOS but since it is a simulator you can run it outside of your project code) http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135728/using-applescript-to-lock-screen

Comment: I want it to be a part of my test suite, is that possible?

Comment: Running apple script script from an iOS project is not an option as far as I know. You can create a shell file that will run xcodebuild that will run your test suite, and also run an Apple script at the same time. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/08-automation.html

Comment: Isn't it part of fast lane's snapshot?

Comment: Are you looking for code, or for a way to lock the simulator (cmd+L)?

Comment: @RoyK i'm using fastlane snapshot for this, not sure where would i stick it

Comment: @FlorianBurel yes, but the 'make a screenshot of a locked simulator' is not :)

Comment: @Michael specifialy from code

Comment: I found this command line : " xcrun simctl  " it allow you to control the simulator, but I see nothing about pressing the home button :(

Comment: @FlorianBurel well the home button can actually be pressed from tests (XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().pressButton(.Home)) , but not the power button unfortunately

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a private method in XCUIDevice, so you can lock device/simulator using it.

Example for Swift 3:

```
import XCTest

class LockTests: XCTestCase {
  func testExample() {
    XCUIDevice.shared().perform(NSSelectorFromString("pressLockButton"))

    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2)
    localNotification.alertBody = "This is local notification"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    localNotification.category = "Message"
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
  }
}
```

And will receive something like this:

[image]

I have no experience with snapshot tool you are using, but you need to know that moving to locking state takes time, so it might be useful to wait a bit of time before creating snapshot (you can use code like this):

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)
while date.timeIntervalSinceNow > 0 {
  CFRunLoopRunInMode(CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode, 0.1, true)
}
```

Also, you can return to SpringBoard in the end of the test by calling (iOS 10 only):

```
XCUIDevice.shared().press(.home)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: just FYI, I used XCUIDevice.sharedDevice.performSelector("pressLockButton")

Comment: Was wrong about selectors, will update my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, looking the exact same thing.

Comment: XCUIDevice.shared().perform(NSSelectorFromString("pressLockButton")) helps me lock the phone. On a side note, it also helps in silencing an incoming call.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we unlock the device by XCTest/Swift after locking in this way? @RomanErmolov